# Define Groovy closure with kwargs and varargs

Tags: groovy, closures, variadic-functions

I've come across an inconsistency between Groovy functions and closures that has me stumped.

I can define a function with signature `def foo(Map kwargs=[:], ... varargs){...}` that does pretty much exactly what I expect it to. It takes pretty much every named and unnamed argument I give it. It also takes no arguments and works correctly.

I cannot find a similar way of defining a closure that has an identical signature. As a quick demonstration, when I run the following four lines:

```
def foo(Map kwargs=[:], ...args ){"kwargs=${kwargs.toString()} args=${args.toString()}"}
def bar = { Map kwargs=[:], ...args -> "kwargs=${kwargs.toString()} args=${args.toString()}"}
println foo(1:1,2:2)
println bar(1:1,2:2)
```

I get the following output:

```
> groovy test.groovy
kwargs=[1:1, 2:2] args=[]
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test$_run_closure1.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[1:1, 2:2]]
Possible solutions: any(), any(), doCall([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure) groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test$_run_closure1.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[1:1, 2:2]]
Possible solutions: any(), any(), doCall([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at test.run(test.groovy:4)
```

Running with `Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.8.0_131 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`

I would like to write a closure that can take any number of named or unnamed arguments, including no arguments at all. Is this possible?

Comment: Warning, nitpicking: Groovy has no named arguments -- just Maps

Answer (score 2):

#### Investigation

I've played around a little bit with your example and I've found out what is going on in this case.

```
def bar = { Map kwargs = [:], ... args -> "kwargs=${kwargs.toString()} args=${args.toString()}" }
bar.class.methods.findAll { it.name == 'doCall' }.each { println it }
```

This is the closure you've defined and here is the output of the `println` (we iterate over all methods defined in this anonymous class and print only those with name `doCall`):

```
public java.lang.Object cls$_run_closure1.doCall(java.lang.Object[])
public java.lang.Object cls$_run_closure1.doCall(java.util.Map,java.lang.Object[])
```

Here we have only two possible signatures for calling the closure - we are missing a signature with single `java.util.Map` parameter to satisfy your expectation.

#### Solution

If we do a small change - apply a default value to `...args` array parameter, like:

```
def bar2 = { Map kwargs = [:], ... args = [] -> "kwargs=${kwargs.toString()} args=${args.toString()}" }
bar2.class.methods.findAll { it.name == 'doCall' }.each { println it }
```

Then this is the output of `println`:

```
public java.lang.Object cls$_run_closure4.doCall(java.util.Map)
public java.lang.Object cls$_run_closure4.doCall(java.util.Map,java.lang.Object[])
public java.lang.Object cls$_run_closure4.doCall()
```

As you can see there is a signature with single `java.util.Map` and you can call this `bar2` closure as you expect:

```
bar2(1:1,2:2)
```

> kwargs=[1:1, 2:2] args=[]

and

```
bar2(1:1,2:2,3,4)
```

> kwargs=[1:1, 2:2] args=[3, 4]

Oh, and btw - I've tested it with Groovy `2.4.8`, I don't have any older version to test it with. Please let us know if it works with `1.8.x` as well.

This is quite interesting case I must admit. I'm also curious if this is a bug or is this a correct behavior designed for groovy's closures. Maybe someone with deep groovy internals knowledge can give us a hint :)

Comment: If I try `bar2(1,2,3)` I get another MissingMethodException; that works for both `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

as workaround MethodClosure could be used:

```
def foo(Map kwargs=[:], ...args ){"kwargs=${kwargs.toString()} args=${args.toString()}"}
def cfoo = this.&foo
println cfoo.getClass()
println cfoo(1:1,2:2)
```

output:

```
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure
kwargs=[1:1, 2:2] args=[]
```